# Cannot open the excel file by explorer

Tags: excel, vba

Please advise as to what is wrong in my coding, it is opening the only PDF file and not the excel. I want to make it dynamic so that we can open any type of file or folder.

```
 myFileNameDir = Sheet3.Range("V7").Value
 Workbooks.Open fileName:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
 Set ws1 = Worksheets("Tracker")
 str = CStr(ListView11.SelectedItem.SubItems(8))
 Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & str, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: What about `Shell str`?